# How to fix error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to deploy Certigo certificate on nginx server.

My nginx config is the following:

```
    server {
       ...
       ssl_certificate "/etc/myfolder/bundle.crt";
       ssl_certificate_key "/etc/myfolder/mydomain_com.key";
       ...
    }
```

From these files I generate bundle.crt:

```
root_ca.crt
mydomain_com.crt
mydomain_com.csr
mydomain_com.key
```

I tried both

```
cat root_ca.crt mydomain_com.csr visitele_com.crt > bundle3.crt
cat root_ca.crt mydomain_com.crt > bundle2.crt
```

and I get in both cases:

```
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey("/myfolder/mydomain_com.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've looked carefully at newlines and number of '-'-s, it looks correct.

Comment: In the 'bundle' file you give `ssl_certificate` your server cert i.e. `mydomain.crt` should be FIRST, and any chain/root cert(s) _after_ it. The CSR should not be included at all. [See the documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate). This is not a programming or development issue, and is offtopic for stackoverflow, so I am not answering.